# Limit number of parallel requests to spring boot actuator health

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We are using spring boot actuator to get health status of an application, my understanding is that request for health check will be handled by thread out of thread pool that is used to serve actual service requests.

Is there a way to limit number of requests for health endpoint to prevent a DDOS type starvation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Boot Throttling community library. I think you could restrict DDOS access to your endpoints (Actuator or otherwise) using it's configuration.
https://github.com/weddini/spring-boot-throttling

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to reduce DDOS vulnerability on the `/health` endpoint is to have your health checks run on a separate thread pool.

This ensures that:

- no more than one health indicator concurrently runs at any given time against an underlying service
- your `/health` endpoint returns instantly (as it returns healths pre-calculated on different threads).

For this purpose, and if you are using Spring Boot >= 2.2, you can use the separate library [spring-boot-async-health-indicator](https://github.com/antoinemeyer/spring-boot-async-health-indicator/) to run your healthchecks on a separate thread pool by simply annotating them with `@AsyncHealth`.

*Disclaimer: I created this library to address this issue (among others)*